# To which subspace does $v_4$ belong?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, solution-verification

Let $h\in\mathbb{R}, h\neq 0$ and three vectors
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{pmatrix},\quad \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ h\\ h\\ 2
\end{pmatrix}\quad\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1+h\\ 2h+1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Let $$v_4=\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 0
\end{pmatrix} \quad\mbox{ and }\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}
1& 2& 1\\
0& h& 1+h\\
0& h & 2h+1\\
1& 2& 1
\end{pmatrix}.$$
If C(A) is the column space of $A$ and $N(A)$ is the null space of $A$, to which of these belongs $v_4$?

My solution: Now, since $h\neq 0$, thus $v_1, v_2, v_3$ are linearly independent, so
$$
C(A) =\left\{
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 0\\ 0\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}
2\\ h\\ h\\ 2
\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ 1+h\\ 2h+1\\ 1
\end{pmatrix}\right\},
$$
while dim$N(A) = 3-{\rm rank}(A)=0$, do that $N(A) =\{0\}$ and then $v_4$ does belong nither to $C(A)$ nor $N(A)$.

Is my solution right? Could anyone please help me?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concerning the fact that $v_4\notin C(A)$, you did not justify it. You can say that, for instance, since $h\ne0$, the set $\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ is linearly independent. And $v_4\notin N(A)$ because $N(A)$ is a set of vectors of $\Bbb R^3$, whereas $v_4\in\Bbb R^4$.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It is clear why $v_4\notin N(A)$, but it also true that $v_4\notin C(A)$?

Comment: Yes. I've put a justification of that assertion in my answer.

Comment: Thanks. If, for example, we allow $h$ to be 0, thus it is still true that $v_4\notin N(A)$ since it is a set of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^3$, isn't it? and barely in $C(A)$ since we have $C(A) = \{(1, 0, 0, 1), (1, 1, 1, 1)\}$, isn't it?

Comment: If $h=0$, the argument that I used fails, but, yes, it will be still true that $v_4\notin C(A)$, because then$$C(A)=\left\{(a,b,b,a)\,\middle|\,a,b\in\Bbb R^4\right\},$$and $v_4$ doesn't belong to it.